# JIRA hangs on clicking 'Create Issue' button after database import

Tags: screen, jira, freeze

This is pretty weird, but I'm wondering if someone might have some insight here.

I am automating the creation of several sub-tasks on the creation of a certain issue type through the use of a Screen Scheme. This is working fine on the deployed instance of JIRA, but in order to test it, I dumped the database and imported it to a development instance.

So, everything shows up fine (the Screen Scheme, the fields, assigned to the right Project, etc.), but when I hit the 'Create Issue' button in the Issue creation screen, JIRA hangs up. Eventually it may finish, but even when it does, none of the sub-tasks are created.

Further, not only is the new Issue type affected, but I can no longer create *any* issues without JIRA hanging. Again, sometimes creating the Issue after several minutes, sometimes hanging beyond my level of patience.

Here's some log:

```
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] Exception in thread "QuartzWorker-1" Exception in thread "QuartzWorker-0" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at java.util.HashMap.addEntry(HashMap.java:753)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at java.util.HashMap.put(HashMap.java:385)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at java.util.HashSet.add(HashSet.java:200)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at java.util.AbstractCollection.addAll(AbstractCollection.java:305)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.atlassian.crowd.model.application.DirectoryMapping.<init>(DirectoryMapping.java:69)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] Jan 30, 2013 9:37:05 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor processChildren
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.atlassian.crowd.embedded.ofbiz.OfBizApplication$1.apply(OfBizApplication.java:70)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] SEVERE: Exception invoking periodic operation: 
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.atlassian.crowd.embedded.ofbiz.OfBizApplication$1.apply(OfBizApplication.java:67)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.google.common.collect.Lists$TransformingRandomAccessList.get(Lists.java:431)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at java.nio.ByteBuffer.wrap(ByteBuffer.java:350)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at java.util.AbstractList$Itr.next(AbstractList.java:345)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at java.nio.ByteBuffer.wrap(ByteBuffer.java:373)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.google.common.collect.Iterators$8.next(Iterators.java:696)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at java.lang.StringCoding$StringEncoder.encode(StringCoding.java:237)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.google.common.collect.Iterators$7.computeNext(Iterators.java:602)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at java.lang.StringCoding.encode(StringCoding.java:272)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.google.common.collect.AbstractIterator.tryToComputeNext(AbstractIterator.java:135)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at java.lang.String.getBytes(String.java:946)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.google.common.collect.AbstractIterator.hasNext(AbstractIterator.java:130)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at java.io.UnixFileSystem.getLastModifiedTime(Native Method)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.atlassian.crowd.manager.application.ApplicationServiceGeneric.findUserByName(ApplicationServiceGeneric.java:242)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at java.io.File.lastModified(File.java:826)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.atlassian.crowd.manager.application.ApplicationServiceGeneric.isUserNestedGroupMember(ApplicationServiceGeneric.java:1413)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.checkResources(HostConfig.java:1158)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.atlassian.crowd.embedded.core.CrowdServiceImpl.isUserMemberOfGroup(CrowdServiceImpl.java:261)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.check(HostConfig.java:1271)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.atlassian.crowd.embedded.core.CrowdServiceImpl.isUserMemberOfGroup(CrowdServiceImpl.java:266)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:296)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.atlassian.crowd.embedded.core.DelegatingCrowdService.isUserMemberOfGroup(DelegatingCrowdService.java:70)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.atlassian.crowd.embedded.core.FilteredCrowdServiceImpl.isUserMemberOfGroup(FilteredCrowdServiceImpl.java:194)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.atlassian.jira.security.roles.actor.GroupRoleActorFactory$GroupRoleActor.contains(GroupRoleActorFactory.java:93)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.backgroundProcess(ContainerBase.java:1337)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.atlassian.jira.security.roles.actor.GroupRoleActorFactory$GroupRoleActor.contains(GroupRoleActorFactory.java:84)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1601)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.atlassian.jira.security.roles.CachingProjectRoleAndActorStore$CachedDefaultRoleActors.contains(CachingProjectRoleAndActorStore.java:499)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.atlassian.jira.notification.type.ProjectRoleSecurityAndNotificationType.hasPermission(ProjectRoleSecurityAndNotificationType.java:159)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1610)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.atlassian.jira.permission.DefaultPermissionSchemeManager.hasSchemePermission(DefaultPermissionSchemeManager.java:415)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.run(ContainerBase.java:1590)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.atlassian.jira.permission.DefaultPermissionSchemeManager.hasPermission(DefaultPermissionSchemeManager.java:380)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.atlassian.jira.permission.DefaultPermissionSchemeManager.hasSchemeAuthority(DefaultPermissionSchemeManager.java:323)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.atlassian.jira.security.AbstractPermissionManager.hasProjectPermission(AbstractPermissionManager.java:228)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.atlassian.jira.security.AbstractPermissionManager.hasPermission(AbstractPermissionManager.java:155)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.atlassian.jira.security.AbstractPermissionManager.hasPermission(AbstractPermissionManager.java:140)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.atlassian.jira.security.AbstractPermissionManager.getProjectObjectsWithPermission(AbstractPermissionManager.java:360)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.atlassian.jira.security.AbstractPermissionManager.getProjectObjects(AbstractPermissionManager.java:319)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.atlassian.jira.security.ThreadLocalCachingPermissionManager.getProjectObjects(ThreadLocalCachingPermissionManager.java:36)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.lucene.store.IndexInput.clone(IndexInput.java:218)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.lucene.store.BufferedIndexInput.clone(BufferedIndexInput.java:192)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.lucene.index.CompoundFileReader$CSIndexInput.clone(CompoundFileReader.java:227)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.lucene.index.SegmentTermDocs.<init>(SegmentTermDocs.java:48)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.lucene.index.SegmentReader.termDocs(SegmentReader.java:1030)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.lucene.index.DirectoryReader$MultiTermDocs.termDocs(DirectoryReader.java:1200)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.lucene.index.DirectoryReader$MultiTermDocs.termDocs(DirectoryReader.java:1187)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.lucene.index.DirectoryReader$MultiTermDocs.read(DirectoryReader.java:1146)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.lucene.search.TermScorer.nextDoc(TermScorer.java:130)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.lucene.util.ScorerDocQueue.topNextAndAdjustElsePop(ScorerDocQueue.java:118)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.lucene.search.DisjunctionSumScorer.advanceAfterCurrent(DisjunctionSumScorer.java:200)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.lucene.search.DisjunctionSumScorer.nextDoc(DisjunctionSumScorer.java:170)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.lucene.search.BooleanScorer2.nextDoc(BooleanScorer2.java:332)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.lucene.search.ConjunctionScorer.nextDoc(ConjunctionScorer.java:134)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.lucene.search.BooleanScorer2.nextDoc(BooleanScorer2.java:332)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.lucene.util.OpenBitSetDISI.inPlaceOr(OpenBitSetDISI.java:52)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.lucene.util.OpenBitSetDISI.<init>(OpenBitSetDISI.java:32)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.lucene.search.CachingWrapperFilter.docIdSetToCache(CachingWrapperFilter.java:210)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.lucene.search.CachingWrapperFilter.getDocIdSet(CachingWrapperFilter.java:234)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.lucene.search.IndexSearcher.searchWithFilter(IndexSearcher.java:277)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.lucene.search.IndexSearcher.search(IndexSearcher.java:233)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.lucene.search.IndexSearcher.search(IndexSearcher.java:181)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.lucene.search.Hits.getMoreDocs(Hits.java:113)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.lucene.search.Hits.<init>(Hits.java:90)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.lucene.search.Searcher.search(Searcher.java:74)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.atlassian.jira.index.DelegateSearcher.search(DelegateSearcher.java:153)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.atlassian.jira.issue.search.providers.LuceneSearchProvider.runSearch(LuceneSearchProvider.java:441)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.atlassian.jira.issue.search.providers.LuceneSearchProvider.getHits(LuceneSearchProvider.java:252)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.atlassian.jira.issue.search.providers.LuceneSearchProvider.search(LuceneSearchProvider.java:316)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.atlassian.jira.issue.search.providers.LuceneSearchProvider.search(LuceneSearchProvider.java:87)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.atlassian.jira.issue.search.providers.LuceneSearchProvider.search(LuceneSearchProvider.java:76)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.my-corp.jira.plugin.JQL.searchForResults(JQL.java:54)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] 2013-01-30 09:37:06,887 http-2990-6 ERROR jbeck 569x2541x1 170hluk 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%0 /secure/CreateIssueDetails.jspa [atlassian.event.internal.EventPublisherImpl] There was an exception thrown trying to dispatch event 'com.atlassian.jira.event.issue.IssueEvent@59a1f1dd[issue=JBT-2,comment=<null>,worklog=<null>,changelog=<null>,eventTypeId=1,sendMail=true,params={eventsource=workflow, baseurl=http://jira.my-corp.com},subtasksUpdated=false]' from the invoker 'com.atlassian.event.internal.SingleParameterMethodListenerInvoker@67d8ef2f'.
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.atlassian.event.internal.SingleParameterMethodListenerInvoker.invoke(SingleParameterMethodListenerInvoker.java:54)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.atlassian.event.internal.AsynchronousAbleEventDispatcher$2.run(AsynchronousAbleEventDispatcher.java:60)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.atlassian.event.internal.AsynchronousAbleEventDispatcher$1.execute(AsynchronousAbleEventDispatcher.java:28)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.atlassian.event.internal.AsynchronousAbleEventDispatcher.dispatch(AsynchronousAbleEventDispatcher.java:56)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.atlassian.event.internal.EventPublisherImpl.invokeListeners(EventPublisherImpl.java:151)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.atlassian.event.internal.EventPublisherImpl.publish(EventPublisherImpl.java:70)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.atlassian.multitenant.event.DefaultPeeringEventPublisherManager.publish(DefaultPeeringEventPublisherManager.java:17)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.atlassian.multitenant.event.PeeringEventPublisher.publish(PeeringEventPublisher.java:23)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.atlassian.jira.event.issue.IssueEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(IssueEventDispatcher.java:254)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.atlassian.jira.event.issue.IssueEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(IssueEventDispatcher.java:183)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.atlassian.jira.workflow.function.event.FireIssueEventFunction.execute(FireIssueEventFunction.java:57)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.opensymphony.workflow.AbstractWorkflow.executeFunction(AbstractWorkflow.java:869)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.opensymphony.workflow.AbstractWorkflow.transitionWorkflow(AbstractWorkflow.java:1265)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.opensymphony.workflow.AbstractWorkflow.initialize(AbstractWorkflow.java:618)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.atlassian.jira.workflow.OSWorkflowManager.createIssue(OSWorkflowManager.java:815)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.atlassian.jira.issue.managers.DefaultIssueManager.createIssue(DefaultIssueManager.java:461)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.atlassian.jira.issue.managers.DefaultIssueManager.createIssue(DefaultIssueManager.java:383)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.atlassian.jira.bc.issue.DefaultIssueService.create(DefaultIssueService.java:193)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.atlassian.jira.bc.issue.DefaultIssueService.create(DefaultIssueService.java:207)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.atlassian.jira.web.action.issue.CreateIssueDetails.createIssue(CreateIssueDetails.java:95)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.atlassian.jira.web.action.issue.CreateIssueDetails.doExecute(CreateIssueDetails.java:71)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at webwork.action.ActionSupport.execute(ActionSupport.java:165)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.atlassian.jira.action.JiraActionSupport.execute(JiraActionSupport.java:76)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at webwork.interceptor.DefaultInterceptorChain.proceed(DefaultInterceptorChain.java:39)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at webwork.interceptor.NestedInterceptorChain.proceed(NestedInterceptorChain.java:31)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at webwork.interceptor.ChainedInterceptor.intercept(ChainedInterceptor.java:16)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at webwork.interceptor.DefaultInterceptorChain.proceed(DefaultInterceptorChain.java:35)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at webwork.dispatcher.GenericDispatcher.executeAction(GenericDispatcher.java:205)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at webwork.dispatcher.GenericDispatcher.executeAction(GenericDispatcher.java:143)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.atlassian.jira.web.dispatcher.JiraWebworkActionDispatcher.service(JiraWebworkActionDispatcher.java:152)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.atlassian.jira.web.filters.steps.ChainedFilterStepRunner.doFilter(ChainedFilterStepRunner.java:74)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.atlassian.core.filters.HeaderSanitisingFilter.doFilter(HeaderSanitisingFilter.java:44)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.IteratingFilterChain.doFilter(IteratingFilterChain.java:46)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter$1.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:66)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.atlassian.applinks.core.rest.context.ContextFilter.doFilter(ContextFilter.java:25)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:74)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.IteratingFilterChain.doFilter(IteratingFilterChain.java:42)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter$1.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:66)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.atlassian.labs.httpservice.resource.ResourceFilter.doFilter(ResourceFilter.java:59)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:74)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.IteratingFilterChain.doFilter(IteratingFilterChain.java:42)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.ServletFilterModuleContainerFilter.doFilter(ServletFilterModuleContainerFilter.java:77)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.ServletFilterModuleContainerFilter.doFilter(ServletFilterModuleContainerFilter.java:63)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.atlassian.jira.web.filters.accesslog.AccessLogFilter.executeRequest(AccessLogFilter.java:103)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.atlassian.jira.web.filters.accesslog.AccessLogFilter.doFilter(AccessLogFilter.java:87)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.atlassian.jira.security.xsrf.XsrfTokenAdditionRequestFilter.doFilter(XsrfTokenAdditionRequestFilter.java:54)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.opensymphony.sitemesh.webapp.SiteMeshFilter.obtainContent(SiteMeshFilter.java:129)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.opensymphony.sitemesh.webapp.SiteMeshFilter.doFilter(SiteMeshFilter.java:77)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.atlassian.jira.web.filters.PathExclusionFilter.doFilter(PathExclusionFilter.java:118)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.atlassian.core.filters.AbstractHttpFilter.doFilter(AbstractHttpFilter.java:31)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.IteratingFilterChain.doFilter(IteratingFilterChain.java:46)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.ServletFilterModuleContainerFilter.doFilter(ServletFilterModuleContainerFilter.java:77)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.ServletFilterModuleContainerFilter.doFilter(ServletFilterModuleContainerFilter.java:63)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.atlassian.seraph.filter.SecurityFilter.doFilter(SecurityFilter.java:211)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.atlassian.security.auth.trustedapps.filter.TrustedApplicationsFilter.doFilter(TrustedApplicationsFilter.java:98)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.atlassian.seraph.filter.BaseLoginFilter.doFilter(BaseLoginFilter.java:150)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.atlassian.jira.web.filters.JiraLoginFilter.doFilter(JiraLoginFilter.java:70)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.IteratingFilterChain.doFilter(IteratingFilterChain.java:46)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter$1.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:66)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.atlassian.oauth.serviceprovider.internal.servlet.OAuthFilter.doFilter(OAuthFilter.java:71)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:74)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.IteratingFilterChain.doFilter(IteratingFilterChain.java:42)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.ServletFilterModuleContainerFilter.doFilter(ServletFilterModuleContainerFilter.java:77)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.ServletFilterModuleContainerFilter.doFilter(ServletFilterModuleContainerFilter.java:63)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.atlassian.util.profiling.filters.ProfilingFilter.doFilter(ProfilingFilter.java:99)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.atlassian.jira.web.filters.JIRAProfilingFilter.doFilter(JIRAProfilingFilter.java:19)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.atlassian.johnson.filters.AbstractJohnsonFilter.doFilter(AbstractJohnsonFilter.java:71)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter.doFilter(UrlRewriteFilter.java:350)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.atlassian.gzipfilter.GzipFilter.doFilterInternal(GzipFilter.java:81)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.atlassian.gzipfilter.GzipFilter.doFilter(GzipFilter.java:51)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.IteratingFilterChain.doFilter(IteratingFilterChain.java:46)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter$1.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:66)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.atlassian.fastdev.AutoReloadFilter.doFilter(AutoReloadFilter.java:63)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:74)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.IteratingFilterChain.doFilter(IteratingFilterChain.java:42)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter$1.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:66)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.sysbliss.jira.plugins.workflow.servlet.JWDSendRedirectFilter.doFilter(JWDSendRedirectFilter.java:25)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:74)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.IteratingFilterChain.doFilter(IteratingFilterChain.java:42)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.ServletFilterModuleContainerFilter.doFilter(ServletFilterModuleContainerFilter.java:77)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.ServletFilterModuleContainerFilter.doFilter(ServletFilterModuleContainerFilter.java:63)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.atlassian.jira.web.filters.steps.ChainedFilterStepRunner.doFilter(ChainedFilterStepRunner.java:74)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.atlassian.core.filters.cache.AbstractCachingFilter.doFilter(AbstractCachingFilter.java:33)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.atlassian.core.filters.AbstractHttpFilter.doFilter(AbstractHttpFilter.java:31)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.atlassian.core.filters.encoding.AbstractEncodingFilter.doFilter(AbstractEncodingFilter.java:41)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.atlassian.core.filters.AbstractHttpFilter.doFilter(AbstractHttpFilter.java:31)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.atlassian.jira.web.filters.PathMatchingEncodingFilter.doFilter(PathMatchingEncodingFilter.java:49)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.atlassian.core.filters.AbstractHttpFilter.doFilter(AbstractHttpFilter.java:31)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.atlassian.jira.web.monitor.ActiveRequestsFilter$PassToChainFilterFunc.doFilter(ActiveRequestsFilter.java:346)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.atlassian.jira.web.monitor.ActiveRequestsFilter$DebugLogFilterFunc.doFilter(ActiveRequestsFilter.java:463)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error states:

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

so, first try to [increase Jira memory](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/Increasing+JIRA+Memory):

- In your `<JIRA Installation Directory>/bin` (or `<Tomcat Installation Directory>/bin` for JIRA WAR installations), open the `setenv.sh` file.
- Find the sections `JVM_MINIMUM_MEMORY=` and `JVM_MAXIMUM_MEMORY=`
- See [Diagnosis](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/Increasing+JIRA+Memory#IncreasingJIRAMemory-guidance) above and enter the appropriate values.

For more information check out the [JIRA Crashes Due to 'OutOfMemoryError Java heap space'](https://confluence.atlassian.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=191069) page

If all else fails, I suggest you'll  try asking at [answers.atlassian.com](https://answers.atlassian.com) where you could ask Jira's support people.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. For some reason I don't seem to have a setenv.h. Can I just create this file and add the line you mentioned?

Comment: doesn't make sense.. is your Jira installed on linux server? if so, try running `find /-name 'setenv.sh'` to find the file.  Which Jira version?

Comment: btw the filename is `setenv.sh` and not `setenv.h`

Comment: These are all I found: 
/opt/local/var/macports/sources/rsync.macports.org/release/tarballs/ports/java/tomcat5/files/setenv.sh 
.../tomcat6/files/setenv.sh 
/Users/jbeck/jira source/atlassian-jira-4.4-source/jira-project/jira-distribution/jira-standalone-distribution/src/main/tomcat/bin/setenv.sh 
/Users/jbeck/jira source/atlassian-jira-5.1.7-source/jira-project/jira-distribution/jira-standalone-distribution/src/main/tomcat/bin/setenv.sh 
/workspace/atlassian-jira-4.4-source/jira-project/jira-distribution/jira-standalone-distribution/src/main/tomcat/bin/setenv.sh

Comment: However, I am developing in: workspace/my-jira-plugin. Shouldn't there be a setenv.sh somewhere in that tree?

Comment: how do you start your Jira instance? if by `service jira restart` check the content of `/etc/init.d/jira`, the `setenv.sh` should be on the same path as `start-jira.sh`

Comment: I'm using atlas-run to start Jira.

Comment: which jira version? paste it's content in your question. if it's long, put it on http://pastebin.com/

Comment: Wow...after changing settings to no effect in atlas-run and .bash_profile, I finally manually overran the setting from the cmd line. So, memory problems are fixed, but the sub-tasks are still not created! Thanks for helping me fix one of my problems!